Creating a Java-Only Project in Android Studio
I'm trying to create a new project in Android Studio, and it contains a Kotlin+Java folder inside the app folder. But I only want a Java folder, no Kotlin files. How can I create a new project according to my preference?
I attempted to create a new project in Android Studio, but it resulted in a project structure that includes a Kotlin+Java folder within the app folder. I was expecting to have only a Java folder without any Kotlin files. My goal is to set up a project that exclusively uses Java. To achieve this, I need guidance on configuring Android Studio to create a new project according to my preference, ensuring that no Kotlin files are included and only the Java folder is present in the app directory.

Does this answer your question? I can't create a new project with java language anymore on Android Studio Flamingo?
